# Non virtual methods can not be intercepted

Tags: c#, unit-testing, mocking, fakeiteasy

I am new to FakeItEasy and try solve a problem.

I have a class

```
 public class Events
 {
 public List<Events> SaveEvents()
 {
 // Call to repository and return 1(success) or -1(fail)
 //If the repository return 1 then need to make another call to save the action in db
 //Sample Code here
   AuditLogService log = new AuditLogService();
   log.CallLog();
 }
 }
```

Here is the Test Code:

```
    [TestMethod]
    public void EventValidation()
    {
        //Arrange           
                             
         var Fakeevents = A.Fake<Events>();
         var log = A.Fake<AuditLogService>();
         var _EventsController = new EventsController(Fakeevents);
        _EventsController.SaveEvents();
        A.CallTo(
             () => Fakeevents.SaveEvents().Retunr(1).AssignsOutAndRefParameters(status)
         A.CallTo(
             () => log.CallLog()).MustHaveHappened(Repeated.AtLeast.Once);
    }
```

I am getting error like "Non virtual methods can not be intercepted"
I want to check whether the Calllog method is called after success or not.

Can anyone please help me on this.

I have a method and inside a method i am initiating another class and calling a method of the class. I want to check from fakeItEasy whether the method is called.

Answer (score 8):

Unfortunately, your title says it all. Non-virtual members cannot be faked, configured, or intercepted, as noted in the documentation under "[What members can be overridden?](https://fakeiteasy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/what-can-be-faked/#what-members-can-be-overridden)".

There's nothing that FakeItEasy can do for you unless you make the member virtual (or promote it to an interface and fake the interface, or something similar).

Comment: var log = A.Fake<AuditLogService>();  use interface instead of AuditLogService. And have this class implement that interface.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to use function?
Like this:

```
Func<YourReturnType> action = () => YourMethod(params); // Act

action.Should().Throw<Exception>(); // Assert
```

Answer (score 0):

var log = A.Fake();

Use interface instead of AuditLogService. And have this class implement that interface

var log = A.Fake();